# Add rows to table dynamically in HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html

How to add new rows to HTML table automatically by getting the data of these rows from a web page.

```
<table class="sortable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Foldername</th>
            <th>Subfolder</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class='$class'>
           <td><span id="albumname"></span></td>
           <td><span id="subdirname"></span></td>              
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Foldername and Subfolder are the headings and no need to change them, but albumname and subdirname must changed by their corresponding values each row.

I get the data using websocket:

```
 $.get("http://localhost:8040/api/album", function (data) {
            console.log("data: ", data);
            var i;
            var j;
            console.log(i);
            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                console.log("start for loop");
                var albname = data[i].Name;
                console.log("albname: ", albname);
                $("#albumname").text(albname);
                var subalbum = data[i].SubAlbums
                for (j = 0; j < subalbum.length; j++) {
                    var subname = data[i].SubAlbums[j];
                    console.log("SubName: ", subname);
                    $("#subdirname").text(subname);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Where is your PHP code? From where you're getting data?

Comment: It looks like you're already setting the values of those cells.  In what way is this code not working?

Comment: `id` is a unique attribute - you can't duplicate it per row try assigning it to the `<tbody>` instead; if you're creating the rows on the fly do that first then append them to the `<tbody>` or overwrite it.

Comment: What are expected results? You are overwriting the text of same cell every iteration of the `for` loop so will end up with value of last item in data array

Comment: @David after I run the code just one row is added with the last values. the code is viewing folders and subfolders in a given directory. It gives only the last folder and the last subfolder in it

Comment: @bilal1409: Well, the code isn't *adding* a row, it's setting the values in the row that's already there.  (Since the elements in the row use `id`, it's hard to tell exactly what you want to do here.  Those have to be unique.)  And you overwrite those values with every iteration of the loop.  You can use something like `.append()` in jQuery to *add* elements to the page.

Comment: Then you need to create html string or jQuery object for new row and append to table

Comment: @David I will try .append(0 command. I think it will make what I need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a class to `<body>` like this,

```
<tbody class="tableBody">

</tbody>
```

And update your jQuery code as follow, assuming there would be multiple subdirename for each album.

```
$.get("http://localhost:8040/api/album", function (data) {
      var i;
      var j;
      $('.tableBody').html('');
      for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        console.log("start for loop");
        var albname = data[i].Name;

        var bodyTr=$('<tr>');

        var albumNameTd=$('<td>');
        albumNameTd.text(albname);

        var subDirNameTd=$('<td>');
        var subDirHtml="";

        var subalbum = data[i].SubAlbums;

        for (j = 0; j < subalbum.length; j++) {
          var subname = data[i].SubAlbums[j];
          subDirHtml+=subname;
          if(j!=subalbum.length-1) {
                subDirHtml+="<br>";
          }
        }
        subDirNameTd.html(subDirHtml);
        bodyTr.append(albumNameTd);
        bodyTr.append(subDirNameTd);
        $('.tableBody').append(bodyTr);
      }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. It gives me what I need

Comment: Great! Happy to help you.

Comment: Can I do the same if I have a list instead of table?

Comment: Yeah you can! Instead of creating `<td>` you can create `<li>` same way.